# How can we aggregate results in a list for one to many relationship in spring jpa

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 tables with structures like this :

```
 Table 1: user
  id, // Primary key
  name,
  email


 Table 2: user_social
  user_id, // Foreign key to user table
  social_channel,
  social_link
```

The data is as follows:

**user:**

> 1, "Ram", "ram@gmail.com"

**user_social:**

> 1, "FB", "fb.com/ram"

> 1, "INSTA", "insta.com/ram"

And the respective JPA entities classes:

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
  @Id
  UUID id;
 
  String name;
  String email;
  
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id.userObj") 
  Set<UserSocial> userSocial = new HashSet<>();
}
```

UserSocial.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_social")
public class UserSocial {
  
  // there is no primary key to the table and the whole row is unique
  @EmbeddedId
  UserSocialId id;

  
  @Embeddable
  public static class UserSocialId {
   
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
   User userObj;

   String social_link;
   String social_channel
  }
}
```

Now when I try to fetch all the user details, I get duplicate results like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Ram",
    "email": "ram@gmail.com",
    "userSocial": [
      { "social_link": "fb.com/ram", "social_channel": "FB" },
      { "social_link": "insta.com/ram", "social_channel": "INSTA" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Ram",
    "email": "ram@gmail.com",
    "userSocial": [
      { "social_link": "fb.com/ram", "social_channel": "FB" },
      { "social_link": "insta.com/ram", "social_channel": "INSTA" }
    ]
  }
]
```

I believe this is because JPA makes a join query and since the `user_social` table has 2 rows in it, it duplicates the result for it. Is there a way where we could aggregate the `user_social` results in a list and thus have a single JSON element in response?

EDIT:
I am using an interface `interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, UUID>` 's method `findAll` method to fetch results.

Comment: How do you fetch the users?

Comment: I am using an interface which extends JpaRepository<User, UUID>. And I am calling the `findAll` method of this interface.